# Mongodb replacing values 2 arrays deep in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have an Mongo Collection that looks like this

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("0000000000000123"),
"user_id": NumberLong(000010),
"location": {
    "addresses": [{
            "number": NumberLong(4410),
            "street": "Test Drive",
            "county": "New York County",
            "city": "New York",
            "state": "NY",
            "zip": "00001",
            "links": [{
                    "image": "http://www.google.com/test",
                    "datetime": " 11/24/1952"
                }, {
                    "image": "http://www.google.com/test2",
                    "datetime": " 11/24/1990"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I need to be able to search for the links array for documents with www.google.com and be able to change it to www.yahoo.com

I tried a few versions of mongo's update but no success

```
$search_string = new MongoRegex("/www.google.com/i");
$collection->update(
        array('location.addresses.links.image' => $search_string),
        array('$set' => array('location.addresses.$.links.$.image' => '')),
        array("multiple" => true)
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after more digging I found that the update position operator ($) can only be used one level deep.

So I decided to use foreach statements by reference to get what i needed done

```
        $collection = new MongoCollection($this->db, 'users');

        $search_string = new MongoRegex("/www.google.com/i");

        $cursor = $collection->find(array('location.addresses.links.image' => $search_string));

        foreach ($cursor as $doc)
        {
            foreach ($doc['location']['addresses'] as &$address)
            {
                foreach($address['links'] as &$link)
                {
                    $link['image'] = str_replace('www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com', $offender['image']);
                }
            }

            $collection->update(array("_id" => $doc['_id']), $doc);
        }
```